# Meteor: Accounts._storedLoginToken is not a function

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts, collectionfs

I am using CollectionFS with GridFS to upload images:

```
Pictures.insert(e.target.files[0], function(err, res) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  this.setState({editing: false});
});
```

However when uploading I get an error:

```
Exception in delivering result of invoking '/cfs.pictures.filerecord/insert': 
TypeError: Accounts._storedLoginToken is not a function
```

I've tried calling `Accounts._storedLoginToken()` in the Meteor shell and it gives the same error.

The error occurs here in the Meteor code:

```
var authToken = '';                                                                                        
if (typeof Accounts !== "undefined") {                                                                     
var authObject = {                                                                                       
  authToken: Accounts._storedLoginToken() || '',                                                         
};                                                                                                    
// Set the authToken                                                                                    
var authString = JSON.stringify(authObject);
  authToken = FS.Utility.btoa(authString);
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add [accounts-base](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/accounts-base) to your project? `Accounts` object does not have the `_storedLoginToken` method until you add a certain pkg such as account-base.